# Webpack re-building each second

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, webpack, jsx, tsx

I'm working with React on ASP.NET Core 2.0, and my webpack became crazy, rebuilding the project each second. I'm not good with Asp.net, so maybe you can help me to fix this problem...Maybe my webpack.config will be helpful.
I just run "dotnet run" and it start's to rebuild project over and over. I'm not sure if it's problem with asp.net configurations or webpack, but it began when I tried to change my .tsx files to .jsx

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
const sharedConfig = () => ({
    stats: { modules: false },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
});

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.tsx' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'] : ['css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader'] }) }
        ]
    },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css'),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
    resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.tsx' },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
            sourceType: 'commonjs2',
            name: './vendor'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
});

return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

};

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?. Please share the code for getting the better help.@Evgeniy Ignatov

Comment: @RohitPoudel When I run the project - it open Chrome and I see this...http://joxi.ru/v29GDolfGjLQYr

Webpack is building the project each second

Comment: could you share your webpack config  ? in case give us a clue...

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora I added it to the question body)